# Creating an anonymous function for callback take too long

Tags: matlab

I have a user interface (created manually, not using GUIDE), that allows me to visualize a very large and complex data set. The data is read only once (this takes about 2-3 minutes), and the GUI is essentially a dynamic view on the data. This means that, as I use the navigation buttons in my GUI, only the view (i.e. a bunch of arrays with indices) and some plots are updated.

My problem is that even this takes too long. In fact, changing the view takes over a second, which is quite annoying when you need to navigate a lot. I have tracked the problem down to the following 4 lines in script:

```
set(ud.h_hid, 'Callback', @(obj, event) handle_hypothesis_change(obj, event, current_cluster_id, msg_idx, static_data));
set(ud.h_cid, 'Callback', @(obj, event) handle_cluster_change(obj, event, static_data));
set(ud.h_prev, 'Callback', @(obj, event) handle_message_change(obj, event, current_cluster_id, msg_idx-1, static_data));
set(ud.h_next, 'Callback', @(obj, event) handle_message_change(obj, event, current_cluster_id, msg_idx+1, static_data));
```

These four lines together take 1.07 seconds (timed with `tic; toc`), amounting to about 99% of the execution time of the script.
These lines only set a callback for four buttons in the GUI (identified by the four handles). In the profiler, I see the following (for the first `set(...)`:

```
my_gui_function>create@(obj,event)handle_cluster_change(obj,event,static_data) (1 call, 0.158 sec)
```

(The 0.158 sec varies from anywhere between 0.1 and 0.25 sec from one profiler run to the next.)

My question is two-fold:

1. Why does this take so long?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: When are those callbacks triggered?

Comment: The callbacks are attached to buttons, so only triggered when the button is clicked. I will clarify in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the callback is slightly unusual and I don't know why it's taking so long.

If I was setting the callbacks I'd do it this way, whther this fixes it or not I don't know - you'd have to try it in your code.

```
set(ud.h_hid, 'Callback', {@handle_hypothesis_change, current_cluster_id, msg_idx, static_data});
set(ud.h_cid, 'Callback', {@handle_cluster_change, static_data});
set(ud.h_prev, 'Callback',{@handle_message_change,current_cluster_id, msg_idx-1, static_data});
set(ud.h_next, 'Callback', {@handle_message_change, current_cluster_id, msg_idx+1, static_data));
```

Note that obj and event will automatically be passed to the function when using this cell array format.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/writing-code-for-callbacks.html

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem, and answers the most important part of my question. I never realized that setting a callback would require a different syntax than what I would use for e.g. `cellfun()`. As for the first part of my question: I've read that the MATLAB garbage collection is not the best; perhaps creating a new anonymous function creates a new scope that the garbage collector must check. The static data I pass consist of several small/medium sized arrays (100-1000 elements range), which might slow down the garbage collector. I hope someone has a better insight in this.